# backupc error: Child exited prematurely

Tags: perl, backup

Suddenly, one server cannot be backed up. i get a strange error message:

```
2011-01-04 10:10:37 host1: Can't fork at /usr/share/backuppc/lib/BackupPC/Lib.pm line 1128.
```

What does this error mean?

All other hosts (with same OS) don't have this problem.

Thanks in advance for any reply. :)

---

```
    $cmd = [split(/\s+/, $cmd)] if ( ref($cmd) ne "ARRAY" );
    print(STDERR "cmdSystemOrEval: about to system ",
          $bpc->execCmd2ShellCmd(@$cmd), "\n")
                    if ( $bpc->{verbose} );
    if ( !defined($pid = open(CHILD, "-|")) ) {  #  <<<<<<<<<  1128
        my $err = "Can't fork to run @$cmd\n";
        $? = 1;
        $$stdoutCB .= $err if ( ref($stdoutCB) eq 'SCALAR' );
        &$stdoutCB($err)   if ( ref($stdoutCB) eq 'CODE' );
        return $err        if ( !defined($stdoutCB) );
        return;
    }
    binmode(CHILD);
    if ( !$pid ) {
        #
        # This is the child
        #
        close(STDERR);
        if ( $ignoreStderr ) {
            open(STDERR, ">", "/dev/null");
        } else {
            open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT");
        }
        alarm(0);
        $cmd = [map { m/(.*)/ } @$cmd];             # untaint
        #
        # force list-form of exec(), ie: no shell even for 1 arg
        #
        exec { $cmd->[0] } @$cmd;
        print(STDERR "Exec of @$cmd failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you have run out of memory? Can't create a new process.

Comment: no, the memory doesn't seem to be the reason. on 2011-01-05 the backup also failed and there was enough free memory

Comment: You might want to post line 1128 (and a few around it for context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message given at the top does not match the error message given in the code for some reason.

The error message lacks reporting [`$ERRNO`](http://p3rl.org/var#%24ERRNO). See [fork(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) for the modes of failure for this system call.

Improve error reporting, then you need not guess about the cause.